# Regex Character Class [-/] works but [/-] does not

Tags: python

1. Please explain as to why the first character class is working, but not the second one

This does work :

```
p = re.compile("\d\d[.-/ ]\d\d[.-/ ]\d\d\d\d")
```

This does not work :

```
p = re.compile("\d\d[./- ]\d\d[./- ]\d\d\d\d")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/pyprg/prac01.py", line 2, in <module>
        p = re.compile("\d\d[./- ]\d\d[./- ]\d\d\d\d")   File "C:\Python361\lib\re.py", line 233, in compile
        return _compile(pattern, flags)   File "C:\Python361\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
        p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)   File "C:\Python361\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
        p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)   File "C:\Python361\lib\sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
        p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, False)   File "C:\Python361\lib\sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
        itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))   File "C:\Python361\lib\sre_parse.py", line 552, in _parse
        raise source.error(msg, len(this) + 1 + len(that)) sre_constants.error: bad character range /-  at position 6
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work either.

Comment: In fact, the first one does work.

Comment: Syntax error due to the extra ` at the end of the line.

Comment: Yes.  you are right.   I have removed that unintended character to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The dash within a range expression has a special meaning (as described by the python regex docs below).  Since it is being interpreted as a range the first example ranges from ascii "." to ascii "/" (hex 2E - 2F).  In the second range it would be ascii "/" to ascii " " (hex 2F - 20) a non consecutive ASCII range resulting in the error.  I'm guessing this isn't what you intended and probably want to escape the dash as \- so that it is interpreted as a literal character.

Ranges of characters can be indicated by giving two characters and separating them by a '-', for example [a-z] will match any lowercase ASCII letter, [0-5][0-9] will match all the two-digits numbers from 00 to 59, and [0-9A-Fa-f] will match any hexadecimal digit. If - is escaped (e.g. [a-z]) or if it’s placed as the first or last character (e.g. [a-]), it will match a literal '-'.

Comment: Thank you so much Rohan.  Great explanation.  
In fact, I am defining this character class to have dd mm and yyyy separated only by any of these characters, i.e. a dash or a forward slash or a space or a dot.